# How to re-enable option from drop down

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I can't re enable a option from my drop down.  For some weird reasons I can disable but can't revert back. Is there any work around on this? I'm using SharePoint 2007

```
$(document).ready(function()
if($("#ctl00_m_g_98b27f90_2d47_4399_9f55_39944c5c3d72_ctl00_ctl04_ctl23_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option[value='Validating']")){
$("#ctl00_m_g_98b27f90_2d47_4399_9f55_39944c5c3d72_ctl00_ctl04_ctl23_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option[value='Analysis']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
else     
if($("#ctl00_m_g_98b27f90_2d47_4399_9f55_39944c5c3d72_ctl00_ctl04_ctl23_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option[value='Resolving']")){

$("#ctl00_m_g_98b27f90_2d47_4399_9f55_39944c5c3d72_ctl00_ctl04_ctl23_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option[value='Analysis']").removeAttr("disabled");
}
});
```

Comment: Why on earth do you have ID's like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#ctl00_m_g_98b27f90_2d47_4399_9f55_39944c5c3d72_ctl00_ctl04_ctl23_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option[value='Validating']")
```

Is a jQuery object, which is always a truthy value (even if nothing's selected).  Therefore, the first `if` statement is always executed.

Instead, use `$('blah').length` to determine if anything was selected.

Though holy cow, find a better way to identify your DOM.

Comment: It seems those ID's are generated dynamically by a Microsoft's software, called SharePoint :)

Comment: @BlackSheep I noticed the tag, 'better way' indicates nuking SharePoint from orbit.

Comment: This really helps. My if statement is always executing the first one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an opening bracket on the `ready` callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() { <--- here
    if($("#ctl00_m_g_98b27f90_2d47_4399_9f55_39944c5c3d72_ctl00_ctl04_ctl23_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option[value='Validating']")){
        $("#ctl00_m_g_98b27f90_2d47_4399_9f55_39944c5c3d72_ctl00_ctl04_ctl23_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option[value='Analysis']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
    else if($("#ctl00_m_g_98b27f90_2d47_4399_9f55_39944c5c3d72_ctl00_ctl04_ctl23_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option[value='Resolving']")){
        $("#ctl00_m_g_98b27f90_2d47_4399_9f55_39944c5c3d72_ctl00_ctl04_ctl23_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_DropDownChoice option[value='Analysis']").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: The `else` statement is an `else if` statement haha. He's not missing anything.

Comment: Oh, that line break was very misleading

Comment: I was confused at first too